# SQL developer single record view

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am currently using SQL developer to look through a table in a database that has many columns. It would be ideal if in the single record view to have the column names sorted? I have been unable to find any option to achieve this.

**EDIT**

The single record view occurs in a couple of places. This includes selecting a table in the list and then selecting the data tab. Then right click on a record.

This does not require writing any SQL.

Comment: `select * from <table name>` Right click on the record in the query view

Comment: I'm not aware of such option(and honestly don't think it's needed). When you use `*` columns are listed in the order(based on their column IDs) they were added to a table. If you need a different order you either need to do it manually `select c1, c2, ..., cn from t1` or construct your query dynamically by querying `user_tab_columns`

Comment: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2016/03/sqldev-trick-alphabetized-column-list-in-the-single-record-viewer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single record view is sorted:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_ID
FROM   user_tab_columns
WHERE  table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
ORDER BY COLUMN_ID;
```

It is just sorted by the `COLUMN_ID` which corresponds to the order in which the columns were defined in the DDL statement(s) that created the table.

It is not sorted alphabetically (which is what you are probably after) - but you can get it sorted alphabetically if you order the columns alphabetically in the original DDL statement or by renaming the columns (to something else and then back to the original name and recreating indexes).

Comment: @EdHeal There is no obvious option to manually change the sort order of the single record view but it is sorted using the order the columns were defined in - as I stated in my answer you can rename the columns to change its `COLUMN_ID` if having it alphabetically is that important to you but there may be [other issues to consider](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2818414600346806270) if you do that.

Comment: I just thought it might be a hidden feature. I find it annoying that the columns are sorted in column id (as you stated) as this is not natural to humans where alphabetic will be easier to find the desired column

Comment: the person who built the table put the columns in that order for a reason, and that's why we show it in that order. if you want them alpha, don't use * like everyone said, write the query with columns you want in the order you want

Comment: Having the ability to either resort the single record view or almost as good, display the column_id to the left of the column name. This would allow you to find column_id 218 for example.